# Quantity Box not showing values in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shopify

I was looking for some help in regards to fixing an issue I am having with a Shopify theme that I have modified. The site is live at the moment and I have noticed an issue with the quantity box where I am able to modify the quantity box by pressing the +/- buttons but the value in button is not visible and I just dont understand why this is.

My site: [https://defineclothing.co/collections/work-wear/products/belted-panel-burgandy-skirt?variant=37162255815]

I have had a look at the original theme that I purchased to see if i can find the difference and I have looked through Friebug but just cant identify where this has gone wrong.

The one thing that I have seen on Firebug is the error:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

but the link for this file (jquery.min.js) is loading from ajax.googleapis.com so not sure how I fix this and if this is what is preventing the values from showing.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise as to how I could fix this.

Theme Site: [http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ella-responsive-shopify-template/full_screen_preview/9691007?_ga=2.49581167.854559603.1509872080-2135413938.1508191597]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to centre align your text inside input and remove unnecessary paddings. Please apply this CSS

```
.product-shop .quantity, .product-shop #quantity {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Victor my friend, you are a star!